# How can I force replacement of a CoreData store with an App update?

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I have an App active in the AppStore which comes with a populated data store.  Now I want to push a new version with a slightly updated schema and a new set of data.  The old data doesn't matter.  If I simply push a new version of the app, I believe existing users will encounter an error with an incompatible datastore... how can I avoid this?  I don't need to migrate existing data, it's all in the new app.

**EDIT**:

FYI, here is the URL where I'm loading the persistent store in my object manager:

```
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyObjects" ofType:@"storedata"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

If you store the persistent store in the main bundle (hence it is read-only), you should not worry, because the new persistent store (also included in your app bundle, I suppose) will just plainly overwrite the old one.

I think that deleting the existing store file and then creating a new one should do it.

If `_storeURL` is the path to your store file, you can delete like this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_storeURL.path])
  [fileManager removeItemAtURL:_storeURL error:&error];
```

Of course, this should be done only on the very first launch of your latest app version. This could be achieved by storing a key in `NSUserDefaults` after deleting/recreating the store and having the program do the delete/create only when on launch the key is not there.

Comment: Thanks, that may do the trick.  I'm actually loading the persistent store from the main bundle. (see my edit) does CoreData create a writable version of this elsewhere?  I was under the impression you couldn't modify files in the main bundle.  Maybe I'm wrong?  My app is definitely saving new objects to the DB.

Comment: you mean that your DB is read-only? if it's in the main bundle, it should be so...

Comment: Now that's the tricky part... it's not read-only.  Either I'm writing into the mainBundle file or there's something going on under the hood.  Wish I could tell which it is.

Comment: I mean, you cannot write in the bundle on a device... you must be copying the store out to some data directory... I bet... :-)

Comment: Oh god... OMG.  I only tested this feature on the simulator. :|  Begin panic mode.

Comment: Yep, this is not working at all like I thought on the device.  Very stupid of me.  Thanks for helping me straighten this out, Sergio.  It makes sense now.